# Analog Video Standard dialog

Tags: c++, delphi, directshow, video-capture, mci

I am creating a program that displays video, for that I'm using Delphi and directshow. I need to select the video input format (NTSC, PAL, SECAM). There is a dialog that lets you make this selection, but I do not know how to display it with delphi or c+ and directshow. What is the procedure to display the dialog that lets you select analog video standard?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you give us a screenshot?

Comment: you will find how to display your input device config dialog box int the AMCAP source code http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373424(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: David, the dialog is this http://www.azcendant.com/images/EasyCapProperties.jpg

Comment: This dialog on the screenshot is not standard. It's supplied by the vendor (EasyCap) of this hardware mentioned on the screenshot. You have choices to `1` show property pages reported by the object `2` show specific pages (no guarantee that they are even applicable to this object) `3` show your own UI wrapping these settings.

Comment: I am selecting the video input using this example

/ / Select the Video Source
TMainForm.VideoCapFiltersClick procedure (Sender: TObject);
var
   PinList: TPinList;
   i: integer;
begin
   CapEnum.SelectGUIDCategory (CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory);
   if VideoCapFilters.ItemIndex <> -1 then
   begin
     VideoSourceFilter.BaseFilter.Moniker: = CapEnum.GetMoniker (VideoCapFilters.ItemIndex);
...
...

Comment: now need to select the video standard! (NTSC, PAL, SECAM)

Answer (score 1):

```
function DisplayPropertyFrame(Filter: IBaseFilter; Handle: THandle): HResult;
var
  PropertyPages: ISpecifyPropertyPages;
  Pages: CAUUID;
  FilterInfo: TFilterInfo;
  pfilterUnk: IUnknown;
begin
  Result := E_FAIL;

  if Filter = NIL then EXIT;

  Result := Filter.QueryInterface(ISpecifyPropertyPages, PropertyPages);

  if (SUCCEEDED(Result)) then
  begin
    Filter.QueryFilterInfo(FilterInfo);
    Filter.QueryInterface(IUnknown, pfilterUnk);

    PropertyPages.GetPages(Pages);
    PropertyPages := NIL;

    OleCreatePropertyFrame(
       Handle,                 
       0,
       0,                   
       FilterInfo.achName,     
       1,                      
       @pfilterUnk,            
       Pages.cElems,           
       Pages.pElems,           
       0,                      
       0,
       NIL                  
    );

    pfilterUnk := NIL;
    FilterInfo.pGraph := NIL;
    CoTaskMemFree(Pages.pElems);
  end;
end;

function DisplayVideoCaptureDeviceProperty( Handle: THandle): HResult;
begin
  Result := DisplayPropertyFrame(VideoCaptureFilter, Handle);
end;
```